# How to transform any 64-bit integer to a uniformly distributed random number in certain interval

Tags: math, random, numbers

Can I transform integers between [Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE] to [0,1] uniformly and randomly? The main purpose is so that I can pick a fraction, e.g. 0.1 and select a uniformly and randomly distributed 10% of longs. If this transformation method is `f(x)`, I can check `f(x)< 0.1` on any long to see if it belongs to the 10% selected numbers. Some important requirements:

- It can be controlled by seeds, so that I can get the same results every time (when I want), and an also change the seed to get completely different result.
- When I increase the fraction from x to y, I want all the selected numbers in x to be also be selected in Y. For example, if 894230 is selected when I pick 10% of numbers, it should also be selected when I pick 20% numbers.
- I can select seeds that won't result in obvious patterns such as `double f(x) { return (x%1000)/1000.0; }`.

  Nice to have (but not necessary):
- I can use a dummy seed that result in an obvious pattern (so that it looks obvious in a unit test).

I use Java, but I don't mind answers in any language that can be rewritten easily in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the job is really just to identify whether `x` belongs to the set of of chosen integers, then I believe the following will achieve all of your first three requirements:

```
(long)anyReasonableHashFunction(x ^ seed) < Long.MAX_VALUE * fraction
```

Comment: does `^` refer to exponent or bitwise xor? Does any reasonable hash function have uniform output between 0 to Long.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: ^ refers to XOR. any reasonable hash function should have property to result in uniform distribution

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::hash<long> hasher;

double f( long x, long seed)
{
    return hasher( x ^ seed) / (double)std::numeric_limits< long>::max();
}
```